# Move Sprite Body randomly using BOX2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am using a tile map+cocos2d+ box2d based game and i have a some issue that how to move randomly enemy body with randomly force in tile map??

Please any one know tell me..

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too unspecific. What *exactly* do you need to know? What is the outcome of supposed to be? Besides that, random forces on moving bodies is not going to get you interesting or believable "enemy" movement.

Comment: Actually in my game i want to move enemy sprite body towards the hero body and i dont know how they work. so please help me if you can...

Comment: So it isn't actually random...?

Comment: it sounds like you might be looking for a pathfinding algorithm. Ray Wenderlich has a great tutorial on this here http://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding